# Why does only one of these functions execute

Tags: javascript, html

When I execute the html file in the browser with the javascript file, and the functions run correctly, but I can only either execute the doorImage.onclick functions or the startButton.onclick functions at the bottom. What I mean is that the page starts with images of closed doors, I can either click the doors and have them change to their designated images and not be able to change anything when I click the start button, or I can click the start button and not be able to change the doors from the closed state. Can someone help me understand why only one of these functions executes, and what I should do instead of this?

I have tried changing the variable types from let to const and that did not change anything.

```js
const doorImage1 = document.getElementById('door1');
const doorImage2 = document.getElementById('door2');
const doorImage3 = document.getElementById('door3');

const startButton = document.getElementById('start');

let beachDoorPath = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/projects/chore-door/images/beach.svg";
let spaceDoorPath = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/projects/chore-door/images/space.svg";
let botDoorPath = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/projects/chore-door/images/robot.svg";
let closedDoor = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/projects/chore-door/images/closed_door.svg";

let numClosedDoors = 3;
let openDoor1;
let openDoor2;
let openDoor3;

const randomChoreDoorGenerator = () => {
  var choreDoor = Math.floor(Math.random() * numClosedDoors);
  if (choreDoor === 0) {
    openDoor1 = botDoorPath;
    openDoor2 = beachDoorPath;
    openDoor3 = spaceDoorPath;

  } else if (choreDoor === 1) {
    openDoor2 = botDoorPath;
    openDoor1 = beachDoorPath;
    openDoor3 = spaceDoorPath;

  } else if (choredoor === 2) {
    openDoor3 = botDoorPath;
    openDoor1 = spaceDoorPath;
    openDoor2 = beachDoorPath;
  }
}

doorImage1.onclick = () => {
  doorImage1.src = openDoor1;
}
doorImage2.onclick = () => {
  doorImage2.src = openDoor2;
}
doorImage3.onclick = () => {
  doorImage3.src = openDoor3;
}

startButton.onclick = () => {
  doorImage1.src = closedDoor;
  doorImage2.src = closedDoor;
  doorImage3.src = closedDoor;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Chore Door!</title>
  <link href="css/robodoor.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Work+Sans" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="header">
    <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/projects/chore-door/images/logo.svg" />
  </div>
  <div class="title-row">
    <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/projects/chore-door/images/star.svg">
    <p class="instructions-title">Instructions</p>
    <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/projects/chore-door/images/star.svg">
  </div>
  <table class="Instructions-row">
    <tr>
      <td class="instructions-number">1</td>
      <td class="instructions-text">
        Hiding behind one of these doors is the ChoreBot
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="instructions-number">2</td>
      <td class="instructions-text">
        Your mission is to open all of the doors without running into the ChoreBot.
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="instructions-number">3</td>
      <td class="instructions-text">
        If you manage to avoid the ChoreBot until you open the very last door, you win!
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="instructions-number">4</td>
      <td class="instructions-text">
        See if you can score a winning streak!
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <div class="door-row">
    <img id="door1" class="door-frame" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/projects/chore-door/images/closed_door.svg">
    <img id="door2" class="door-frame" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/projects/chore-door/images/closed_door.svg">
    <img id="door3" class="door-frame" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/projects/chore-door/images/closed_door.svg">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/robodoor.js"></script>
  </div>
  <div id="start" class="start-row">
    Good Luck
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

openDoor1, 2, 3, and closedDoor are all declared correctly and assigned to an image.

Comment: Your `<script>` tag for the code should be placed right before the `</body>` closing tag.

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your current code is that the function that assigns the paths to `openDoor1`, `openDoor2`, and `openDoor3` is declared, but never called.

To correct this you simply need to add this line of code after you assign the function to `randomChoreDoorGenerator`:

```
randomChoreDoorGenerator();
```

The start button function doesn't need to be called explicitly in your code because, behind the scenes, your browser sees that the start button has been clicked and will execute the function assigned to the start button's `onclick` event automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call randomChoreDoorGenerator() for **openDoor1, openDoor2, and openDoor3** to populate values for image's source.

Also you will have to call randomChoreDoorGenerator() function every time you want randomised value to be populated on for all three door.

You can call **randomChoreDoorGenerator()** from onclick function of every door to get random values everytime.